# How Do i Fix This attempt to index nil with 'CFrame'

Tags: lua, roblox

16:26:29.367  ServerScriptService.Main.Mob:9: attempt to index nil with 'CFrame' -  Server - Mob:9
Can Anyone Help Me I Dont Know What I Did Wrong This My Code

```
    newMob.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = map.Spawn.CFrame
```

I Need Help Can Anyone Help Me

Comment: It seems that the CFrame doesn’t exist. Try checking  if you’re referencing the right part? (Printing its name, for example)